# Angular cannot find name of type

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have installed a type definition like so:

```
npm install --D @types/stripe-checkout
```

Now in `node_modules/@types/stripe-checkout` there is an `index.d.ts` file which, among other stuff, contains the following:

```
<reference types="stripe-v3"/>

interface StripeCheckoutStatic {
    configure(options: StripeCheckoutOptions): StripeCheckoutHandler;
}
```

In one of my components, I am trying to use the type like so:

```
declare var StripeCheckout: StripeCheckoutStatic;
```

The following error gets printed in my terminal:

```
ERROR in src/app/stripe/stripe.component.ts(9,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'StripeCheckoutStatic'.
```

So it seems like it cannot find the type for some reason - even though when I ctrl+click on the type in Visual Studio code, it takes me to the correct file.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is the import path in your `stripe.component.ts` successfully resolving the path for the type definition? (Index.d.ts for stripe-checkout)? Other than that just double check the documentation and make sure you don’t need to import a StripeCheckout module or something within the application’s app.module. I hope this helps!

Comment: @TonyM I don't have any import statement in `stripe.component.ts` for the type definition. I was following this tutorial: https://fireship.io/lessons/stripe-elements-angular/ and he does not import it. Also, he doesn't show any imports in the app.module. :/

Comment: Actually I was wrong before, I was really curious why it wouldn’t work so I installed `@types/stripe-checkout` and did a quick test. In your file `src/tsconfig.app.json` in the “types” section you need to add “@types/stripe-checkout” to that array. That should fix any reference issues.

Comment: @TonyM Thought it didn't fix it at first, but I had to rerun "ng serve" and then it was all good, thanks! I had previously tried to add `stripe-checkout` to the `types` array in `tsconfig.app.json`, as I had seen examples of that from google, but I guess the `@types/` prefix was required in this case?

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Yeah I've had mixed experiences with `@types` and with importing non typescript libraries. It always ends up being a trial and error, but a learning experience :)

Comment: why did modifying the tsconfig.app.json resolve the issue?